# How to validate a signed DLL has been signed by me?

Tags: code-signing

I have created a self generated certificate to sign a DLL. When I load this DLL into my C++ application I am able to validate if the code signing certificate is valid or not by using the WinVerifyTrust api.

But I am not able to find a way to detect that the DLL has been signed by one of my certificates. Even by using the CryptQueryObject api I do not find any useful information.

Does anyone have a idea on how to do this? Or is it event possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CryptVerifyCertificateSignature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380912(VS.85).aspx) isn't what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you sign a certificate using your *private* key, it can only be verified with your *public* key. That's how public-key cryptography works. If you can use a public key to verify the signature, then you know that the corresponding private key **must** have been used to sign it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a version that also works on earlier versions of Windows than the one Bill Zeller showed you, you can use the following:

1. Use `CryptQueryObject` with `CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE`
2. Use `CryptMsgGetParam` with `CMSG_SIGNER_CERT_INFO_PARAM` on the `HCRYPTMSG` you received from the previous call
3. Now use `CertCompareIntegerBlob` to compare your known (certificate) serial number (or numbers, in a loop) against the one in the file

If any of the known serial numbers matches, you're done. If all comparisons fail, it's not your cert.

**Note:** when looking at the serial number of the certificate in the file properties dialog, the bytes shown there appear in the reverse order when compared with the contents of the `PCERT_INFO` (`CERT_INFO::SerialNumber`) you get from the `CryptMsgGetParam`. So make sure that you store your own serial numbers reversed or reverse them before comparison.

**Also note:** you'll still need to have the certificate installed as trusted, in order for `WinVerifyTrust` (not mentioned above) to consider the code signature trusted at all. I just described the part about how to find out it's your own certificate that was used.